# Symfony2 - call some actions in each route

Tags: symfony, twig

I have some things that I have to call in each action, like getting tags from my DB, or number of all articles, etc.
Now I always fire other function in each action where I want to show it. Is there any way to fire some functions without firing them in action which fits to the current route, and assign some twig vars in those functions?

Comment: I suggest you to read something about symfony2. Those you're asking for, are symfony2 base principles and are well explained all over the web

Comment: Oh, thanks. I've read The book. But I din't find an answer there.

Comment: My fault: didn't understand at firsts your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to DonCallisto I made this:

```
<?php

namespace Puzzle\InfobusBundle\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
use Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigEngine;

class MyListener{
    protected $doctrine;
    protected $templating;
    protected $session;
    protected $container;


    /**
     * @param ContainerInterface $container
     */
    public function __construct($security, $doctrine, $session, $templating, $container){
        $this->doctrine=$doctrine;
        $this->session=$session;
        $this->templating=$templating;
        $this->container=$container;
    }

    public function onKernelRequest() {
        $this->container->get('twig')->addGlobal('myVar', 1234);
    }
```

And in app/config/config.yml:

```
services:
    acme_my.exception.my_listener:
        class: Acme\MyBundle\EventListener\MyListener
        arguments: ["@security.context", "@doctrine", "@session", "@templating", "@service_container"]
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.request, method: onKernelRequest }
```

Now code in onKernelRequest fires code on each page, and I can send some vars to twig template.

Answer (score 2):

You can act in that way:

- Create a global "fake" action that will accept every request of a specific "type"
- Define an action dispatcher (as a service) that will route to the right action (or user `$router` symfony2 object, that will do the same as long as you pass exactly the route name as parameter to your "fake" action
- After calling the right action, do all the things you need to do

So, something like this

```
public function actionDispatcher(Request $request, $route_name, $parameters)
{
   /* retrieve the router */
   $router = $this->get('router');
   $myRouteDefaultsArray = $router->getRouteCollection->get('route_name')->getDefaults();
   /* retrieve the correct action */
   $myAction = $myRouteDefaultsArray['_controller'];
   /*use your action here */
   [.....]
   /* fire your functions here */
   [.....]
   /* render the twig template along your variables here */
   [.....]
}
```

}